# After I externally trigger the airflow dag using experimental api it keeps on running and not executing the dag

Tags: airflow, airflow-api

Airflow Dag:

```
def print_hello(**kwargs):
    task_params = kwargs['dag_run'].conf['task_payload']
    print('Hello world a with {}'.format(task_params))


def hello_world():
    args = {
        "start_date": datetime(2022, 5, 1),
        "retries": 1,
        "sla": timedelta(hours=3)
    }

    dag_name = 'hello_world_a'
    dag = dag_utils.create_dag(dag_name, args=args, schedule_interval=None)


    test = PythonOperator(
        task_id='hello_world_printer',
        python_callable=print_hello,
        provide_context=True,
        dag=dag)

    with_done_check((test),
                    date_format="{{ ds }}",
                    run_mode=get_mode())

    return dag
```

Api
curl --location --request POST 'http://loclahost:8080/api/experimental/dags/hello_world_a/dag_runs' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--header 'Cache-Control: no-cache' 
--data-raw '{"conf":"{"mesage":"test"}"}'

Please let me know why my dag is in running state, but not getting excuted

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the month and day values in `start_date`. [`datetime.datetime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) is in year/month/day format. Airflow is most likely waiting for May 1.

Comment: Can I give 2022-01-01 as args?

Comment: I have tried to keep 2022-01-01 as start date, it is still in running state